# Checking if a tag is a valid user

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm programming a bot using discord.py. I have just used client.get_all_members and am trying to check if a user id matches any of them. The issue is, get_all_members gives the members in the form of their name, Name#1234. How can I turn this name into their user id?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`discord.ext.commands.UserConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.UserConverter) which will return the user object, then use the `id` a

```py
usern = 'ARandomPerson#1234'
user = await discord.ext.commands.UserConverter().convert(ctx, usern)
id = user.id
```

Or even better, why not just turn the id into a user

```py
id = 1234567890
user = await discord.ext.commands.UserConverter().convert(ctx, id)
usern = str(user) #Returns name#discriminator

usern in all_members #True/False
all_members.index(usern) #Index of username/IndexError
```

Comment: You can check if `user is None`. In case that is not a valid username

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion. I tried using this and got the error message, "AttributeError: module 'discord.ext' has no attribute 'commands'". I looked it up and discord.ext.commands looks like an alternative way of using commands-I just check if a user's message matches a command. Is there a way to do this without discord.ext.commands, or is it something I should absolutely learn?

Comment: Use `from discord.ext import commands` then you can use `commands.UserConverter`

Comment: Also, you should use discord.ext.commands. It has built in argument parsing and many things better than just on_message